# httpcontext.current.user.identity.name returning blank on server (WebApi)

Tags: vb.net, web

I'm at my wits end. Httpcontext.current.user.identity.name is returning blank.

**Website Structure**

```
\Manage
    default.html
\Controllers
    LoginController.vb
default.html
```

**LoginController.vb**

Returns the current username. This works on the localhost, but not on IIS.

```
Public Function GetValue() As Object

     Return New With {Key .Username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name}

End Function
```

I have also tried:

- Environment.UserName
- System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
- Other variations

**IIS Server**

- Setup to use Basic Authentication on the **Manage** folder
- We have other sites that use this same setup.

**Web.config**

I saw this as a recommended solution in a similar post, but it did not work for me.

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
```

Comment: Which version of the Framework?  Which version(s) of IIS?  Are there any basic differences between your existing sites and this new one?  Have you tried comparing the web.config between sites?

Comment: 4.5. The main difference is this one is using Web API.